# Reducing re-renders in React - Not going as expected

Tags: reactjs, rendering, render, rerender, memo

I am attempting to clean up my app and reduce the amount of re-renders that occur by using the `React.memo` feature, however I am struggling to understand fully why my page/component is re-rendering the amount of times it is. I believe it is down to my Redux usage and the different reducer steps that hit (fire, success, error).

**App.jsx (pseudocode)**

```
console.log("App");
return <div>
    <Switch>
       ...
       <Route render={Home} />
       ...
    </Switch>
</div>

export default App;
```

**Home.jsx**

```
const Home = () => {
   console.log("Home");
   return (
        <div>
          <DashboardBill/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

**Dashboard.jsx**

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    console.log("Dashboard");
    return <div>
        <MyBill/>
    </div>
}

export default memo(Dashboard);
```

**MyBill.jsx**

```
const mapStateToProps = ({billData}) => ({
    billData
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    loadData: () => dispatch(loadBillData)
});

const MyBill = ({billData, loadData}) => {
    console.log("MyBill");
    const [manipulatedData, setManipulatedData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        !billData && loadData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
       billData && setManipulatedData(someUtil.manipulate(billData));
    }, [billData]);

    return <div>{manipulatedData}</div>;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(memo(MyBill));
```

The `dispatch` event ends up in a reducer that has the usual trigger, success and error cases to set the data within the Redux store etc.

When I load the page I am getting the following logging:

[image]

There are a few more `dispatch` events within the main App.jsx going on, but only a couple so that ***could*** account for the extra App mentions in the logs.

Can somebody attempt to explain what is going on here and why my `memo()` usages aren't doing what I am expecting?

> Note: I am importing `memo` like `import React, {memo, useEffect} from 'react';`

Also, how would things be affected if `MyBill` were to have children that themselves made Redux store changes?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand react.memo, render will be optimized if you use the component many times with the same props.
However, in your example, mapDispatchToProps provide a new function reference for `loadData` on every render. So your component is never rendering with the same props.

I guess you can optimize one rendering using `useMemo` hook

```
const MyBill = ({billData, loadData}) => {
    const manipulatedData = useMemo(() => billData ? someUtil.manipulate(billData) : {}, [billData]);

    useEffect(() => {
        !billData && loadData();
    }, []);

    return <div>{manipulatedData}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be something silly like that!